# ClamAV marked spamassassin plugin OLEVBMacro.pm

Tags: spamassassin

ClamAV marked spamassassin plugin OLEVBMacro.pm as malware. I checked the plugin on Virus total, so ClamAV and ESTsecurity marked Malicious.
[Plugin on github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/spamassassin/trunk/lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/OLEVBMacro.pm)

ClamAV react to this line

```
my $mhtml_marker2 = "^mhtml:https?://";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for _programming_ questions. Your question may be suitable for our sibling site [su] but they too will want a somewhat more specific question than "any ideas?"

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to include exclude paths in either the clamd.conf or scan.conf files within the ClamAV configuration settings.

```
ExcludePath ^/usr/local/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin
ExcludePath ^/usr/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin
ExcludePath ^/path/to/OLEVBMacro.pm
```

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions; we don't want to encourage them.